# How can I configure a file redirect environment in VS CODE?

Tags: vscode-debugger

I want to receive the input from input.txt and export the output to output.txt, but I don't know how to change the configuration in launch.json.

I planned it below and tried it, but there is still no change in output.txt and it only outputs from the console.

```
  "version": "0.2.0", 
  "configurations": [ 
  { 
    "name": "Python: something", 
    "type": "python", 
    "request": "launch", 
    "program": "${file}", 
    "console": "integratedTerminal", 
    "args": ["<", "input.txt", ">", "output.txt" ] 
 } 
 ] 
}
```